# how to get the timestamp with current date and microseconds in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way to get the complete timestamp(including date, hour of the day, min, microseconds and timezone) in Node.js?

I am using node version 4.3.0.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is probably just `new Date();`

You might also try `Date.now()` which will give you the current timestamp in milliseconds.

Comment: on the node REPL, you will get a properly formatted date if you use `new Date()` whereas `Date.now()` gives a numeric value, which -i'm assuming- is miliseconds since epoch or similar

Comment: Yes, you're right.  I'm just giving both options ;)

Comment: @Zeus77— *new Date()* returns a Date object. Whether the default string representation is "proper" is unknown since the OP hasn't said what that is.

Comment: @RobG yes, reason I made a *comment* rather than a complete answer :)

Comment: @PatrickGrimard --- I got the answer using,                                                                             var a = new Date();
var startTime = a.toJSON().replace(/T/, ' ').replace(/\..+/, '');                       It gives the output in the format, 2016-03-07 11:33:48